# How to make one remote branch identical to another

Tags: git, git-branch

On origin, I have 2 branches: `master` and `development`.

`master` is ahead of `development` by a few commits and behind by a few commits.

I want the tree of `master` branch to be identical to the one of `development` branch (talking about the tree object of the revisions, not the history, actually). It is fine if I lose anything on the `master` branch, but the `development` branch should be intact.

Reasons for doing this is, we have a workflow where we work on `development` and merge to `master` when we are ready to do a release. Over time there have been some commits made directly to `master`. We want to bring `master` back in sync with `development`.

Can you please share how this can be achieved? One way which I think might work is merge `master` to `development`, then revert the commit from the merge in `development`, and merge `development` to `master`.

Edit: I cannot force push. I need to create a pull request to make any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just push development into remote master (even if by using -f to force it):

```
git push -f origin develop:master
```

Adjust name of remote.

**Another hackish suggestion**

If you want to have master look exactly like develop with a PR with the least amount of work possible, this is what you would want to do:

```
git cat-file -p origin/develop # find the ID of the _tree_ of this revision
git commit-tree -p origin/master -m "Tree of master is now just like develop" id-of-tree-of-last-command # create a new revision with the same tree of develop... this will generate one ID
git checkout -b some-development use-id-printed-by-commit-tree
git push some-remote some-development
```

Now you can create your PR from some-development.... if you *also* want develop to be a parent of this revision, add it as another -p parameter to commit-tree.

Comment: I cannot force push. I need to create a pull request to make any changes.

Comment: If I wanted to have "the same tree" on both branches, I would probably hack a revision with commit-tree that had develop and master as its parents... but not being able to force push? what you are describing is a scenario where you want to replace one branch with the other. why not replace it altogether instead of playing games? Anyway, just me being opinionated.

Comment: and @MarceloFilho given that the branches have diverged, if you try pushing develop onto master, git would keep it from happening because the branches have diverged and that you should merge them... so, force is a must for what I intended to do.

Comment: @eftshift0 I am using a DevOps platform that runs on top of git. There are many high-level policies that are on the origin/remote "branch" that I would have to migrate to the newly created branch if I replaced it, which I am trying to avoid. Besides, I don't have the permissions to delete branches.

Comment: I don’t think this is the right solution. It sounds like the OP just wants a normal merge.

Comment: Was able to force push. Thanks @eftshift0

Answer (score 0):

What you have encountered is a standard Git development problem that we all run into, and because of that a branching methodology has been created.  Some branching strategies are more popular than others.  The 3 most popular are:

1. GitFlow (what it seems like you need): https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
2. GitHub Flow: https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/index.html

I'm going to quickly describe how to solve your issue:

1. In 'develop' branch, do a pull from 'master'.  Resolve any merge conflicts in the 'develop' branch and then commit and push into the 'develop' branch.'
2. Do a build from the 'develop' branch and make sure everything builds and pasts any unit tests if you have any.
3. Complete a Pull Request to get your code into the 'master' branch, and now your 'master' branch and 'develop' branch are now in sync.

This is how to solve your issue going forward:

1. Do your development work in 'develop' branch
2. Do your features in 'feature' branches.  Create Pull Requests to get code from 'feature' branches to 'develop' branch.
3. Merge from 'develop' into 'release' branch, and build package from 'release' branch and deploy to Test environment.
4. Do your testing builds in 'release' branch and testing fixes in the same 'release' branch.
5. After you deploy to production, then merge your code into the 'master' branch and DO NOT TOUCH IT.  This is our golden Production code.
6. If there is a Production issue, branch FROM the 'master' branch into a new branch called 'hotfix' and do commits and builds from here, and deploy into Production for emergency fixes.
7. When done, merge fixes backwards into 'master' branch, then 'release', and 'develop' branch.  Individual developers will absorb the fixes into their 'feature' branches when they are ready.
8. There is a lot I am skipping, but I am hitting the top points on the branching methodology called "GitFlow" mentioned above.  This is a slow process that slows you down on purpose.  You do not have to follow this process, or you can modify this process to suit your needs.  This is a much larger topic that you can spend hours upon hours reading.  Good luck.