Updating branches on GitHub
I have a scenario like below:
I have a release branch and a master branch (both are protected branches). After a release, I want to create a PR to update the master with the release branch but since there are some merge conflicts so here's what I do:

I branch out from master a branch named release_to_master and merge (and resolve conflicts) the release branch into the release_to_master branch.

Then on GitHub I create a PR to merge from release_to_master into the master. Then I merge it using 'squash and merge'.


After that I thought my master branch should be in sync with the release branch but when I try to create another PR to merge the release branch directly into master. I still see commits and file changes there but no merge conflicts anymore.

Was that the correct way to update branches in my scenario?

Why are there still commits and changes when the master should have already been updated to the latest?




I thought my master branch should be in sync with the release branch

A branch is a commit. A commit is a snapshot of your entire project. I assume that by "in sync" you mean that the two branches should be snapshots of your project in an identical state.
Well, the way to know whether the master and release branch are now in an identical state is not to look at commits, but to diff between their current states:
git pull origin master:master
git pull origin release:release
git diff master release

If there is no output from that git diff command, then they are in an identical state and your mission is accomplished.
It is impossible and unnecessary that the two branches should have identical histories or commits; they are different branches, and in any case you know for a fact that master has at least one commit that release does not, namely the squash commit that you asked GitHub to create.
If that diff does produce output, then you failed in your goal (as I understand your goal), because the output represents differences between the state of master and the state of release, and you (as I understand it) do not want there to be any such differences.
And indeed, I expect that that diff will produce output and there will be differences. In fact, I would be very surprised to hear otherwise.
Why? Well, you say you performed a merge. And a merge in Git, by default, comprises the contributions from both branches equally since the point of most recent topological divergence. I have no idea when that was, because you gave no information about how these two branches have been related in the past. A merge does not impose the state of one branch onto the other.
So if your goal was to make the state of master be identical to the state of release, what you did is not a thing that would be expected to accomplish that goal. If it did, you are lucky!

Thanks for your comment.
I used "in sync" to say that I want my master have the latest code from release.
I've tried git diff and true there's no diff between those two branches.
So if your goal was to make the state of master be identical to the state of release, what you did is not a thing that would be expected to accomplish that goal. If it did, you are lucky! According to this, what should I do instead ?

If there's no diff, things have worked as you hoped and there's no problem. Well done!

You asked "what should I do instead?" The problem of making branch A look exactly like branch B has been discussed many times here; some useful approaches, for instance, are at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724304/how-to-make-one-remote-branch-identical-to-another. But whether you can do any of those things with the added restriction that both branches are protected at GitHub — that will depend on the nature of the protection (and you didn't give that info in your question).
